# How to update the Strategy parameters of tree model in Spark MlLib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tree, apache-spark-mllib

I was trying to update the parameter "categoricalFeaturesInfo" in the strategy variable like below in Spark shell:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Strategy    
val treeStrategy = Strategy.defaultStrategy("Classification")
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]((0,4), (1,4))

treeStrategy.setCategoricalFeaturesInfo(categoricalFeaturesInfo)
```

And I got error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Strategy.setCategoricalFeaturesInfo(Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;)V
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
        at <init>(<console>:53)
        at .<init>(<console>:57)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:752)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

According to scala programming guide of spark 1.6.1 (the spark version I have) http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Strategy, I am supposed to be able to update the parameter value using the given function. Does anyone has any clue about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need a **java map** not a **scala map**!

according to the function below:

```
   /**
   * Sets categoricalFeaturesInfo using a Java Map.
   */
  @Since("1.2.0")
  def setCategoricalFeaturesInfo(
      categoricalFeaturesInfo: java.util.Map[java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer]): Unit = {
    this.categoricalFeaturesInfo =
      categoricalFeaturesInfo.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[Int, Int]].asScala.toMap
  }
```

[the code source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/configuration/Strategy.scala)